# C#. Как программе подключиться к БД access, если у пользователя microsoft access не установлен?

Tags: c#, база-данных, access

База данных в access, .mdb (97-2003г)
При подключении к базе данных использую следующую конструкцию

```
public OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection();
public OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
public void loadDb()
    {   
        con1.ConnectionString = Data.connectionString;
        cmd1.Connection = con1;
    }
```

где

```
Data.connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\db.mdb";
```

Проверяю, есть ли подключение таким способом:

```
    public bool checkCon(OleDbConnection con)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

На моем пк подключение работает исправно. У преподавателя пишет, что не может цепануться к бд. (Но у него Access есть на компьютере, однако отсутствует visual)
У знакомых некоторых цепляется (у них тоже установлен acess, visual studio)
У других подключение не создается. (нет access"a, нет visual studio)

Собственно, как быть?
Быть может ConnectionString изменить? Использовать более старые драйвера или как.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде как сам разрешил проблему, корявенько конечно, ну как умею %)
Для начала воспользовался информацией про connectionString
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Затем, 
Data.connectionString у меня формируется таким способом:

```
StreamReader s = File.OpenText(Application.StartupPath + "\\path.txt");
Data.connectionString = s.ReadLine();
s.Close();
Data.connectionString = Data.connectionString + Application.StartupPath + "\\db.mdb";
```

Где path.txt содержит одну строку:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=
```

Answer (score 2):

Так у Вас в решении ответ на Ваш вопрос. Если Вы в первом случае измените "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" на "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" все должно работать. В первом случае вы указываете что у Вас Access 2012 (по-моему, если не ошибаюсь), а во-втором (Jet.OLEDB.4.0) Вы указываете на Access 97-2003. Начиная с Access 2007 там большие изменения произошли.... Я боюсь напутать в версиях, но Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ставится, по-моему, с Net.Framework 4.5..., а Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 стоит даже на ХР.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения.